# How do i insert discrete values like n = 1,2,3,4,5... in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Hello i need to plot a function in gnuplot:

```
h(x) = ((sin(x/2))**2)/((sin(n*x/2))**2)
```

What i don't know is how to set

```
n = ...-2,-1,0,1,2...
```

or maybee

```
n = 1,2,3,4...
```

Soo how do i do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `f(x) = y`: `y` only be dependent upon `x`. A changing `n`, used as presented, is a different equation.

Comment: `n` is inside the first equation but look carefully. So how would i set an increment of 1 for n?

Comment: Are you sure this can't be done in gnuplot? That would be quite sad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function definitions in gnuplot can take multiple parameters:

```
h(x,n) = ((sin(x/2))**2)/((sin(n*x/2))**2)
```

If you want to plot a range of this type of function, you can use the `for` structure:

```
plot for [i=-2:2] h(x,i)
```

or `do for`:

```
do for [i=-2:2] {
    plot h(x,i)
    print i # or do other stuff
}
```